# Install Apache + PHP on CentOS server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, yum

I am trying to use YUM to install Apache and PHP on CentOS but keep getting these errors. Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks!

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * c5-testing: dev.centos.org
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.i386 0:2.2.8-1.el5s2.centos set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================
 Package                 Arch       Version          Repository        Size 
=============================================================================
Installing:
 httpd                   i386       2.2.8-1.el5s2.centos  c5-testing        1.0 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================
Install      1 Package(s)         
Update       0 Package(s)         
Remove       0 Package(s)         

Total download size: 1.0 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
Package perl-libapreq needs perl(Apache::Table), this is not available.
Package perl-libapreq needs perl(mod_perl) >= 1.17, this is not available.
Package perl-libapreq needs perl(mod_perl) >= 1.17, this is not available.
Package apache-devel needs apache = 1.3.41, this is not available.
Complete!
bash-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a testing repository (c5-testing). Have a look at the contents of your directory /etc/yum.repos.d ... normally, once you disable this repository, the issue should go away.

Comment: Thanks but still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Scott, any more details ? What's the output now ?

Comment: sounds like some packages had been installed via this additional repository and they should have been installed via the main centos repos. You may need to uninstall any packages installed via this testing repo and reinstall them via the stable main repos. Once all previously installed packages are brought inline with the versions present in the main repo it should work. Also, disable any other non-standard repos.

Comment: If you need additional packages beyond those provided in the main repos, always install yum-priorities and make sure to set the main repos at the highest priority.

Comment: I decided to re-image the whole thing. Hmm.. now the problem is the thing is missing httpd.conf file. Anyone know how to recreate it?

Starting httpd: fopen: No such file or directory
httpd: could not open document config file /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl startssl: httpd could not be started

Comment: Yep... that was the problem. Using wrong repository. I had to uninstall several prior packages I installed using the TEST repository and then things worked.

Answer (score 0):

which was the command?

Try this:

yum -y update httpd

HTH

Comment: Thanks but doesnt work. httpd is not installed at this point. I ran sudo yum install httpd